# Как сделать скриншот экрана и сохранить изображение в файл?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtimer, скриншот, primaryscreen

Задача заключается в создании **`скриншота`** и получения его из *буфера обмена*.

Использую `pyperclip`, с текстом справляется хорошо, но вот принимает ли изображения - без понятия.

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вам надо сделать? Как скриншот связан с буфером обмена? Вам надо сделать скриншот экрана и показать его в приложении, так ?

Comment: Ну, клавиша принтскрин отправляет ведь снимок в буфер обмена, я правильно понимаю? Нужно его сделать и сохранить в jpg файл. Даже не знаю куда копать.

Comment: Вам надо сделать скриншот экрана и показать его в приложении, так ?

Comment: Сохранить в файл, если совсем точно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> QPixmap QScreen::`grabWindow`(WId window, int x=0, int y=0, int width=-1, int height=-1)
>
> Создает и возвращает растровое изображение, построенное путем захвата содержимого
> заданного окна, ограниченного `QRect(x, y, width, height)`.
>
> Аргументы `(x, y)` определяют смещение в окне, тогда как `(width, height)` задают область,
> которую нужно скопировать. Если ширина отрицательна, функция копирует все до правильной границы окна.
> Если высота отрицательная, функция копирует все до нижней границы окна.
>
> Аргументы смещения и размера указываются в независимых от устройства пикселях.
> Возвращенное растровое изображение может быть больше запрошенного размера при захвате
> с экрана с высоким разрешением.
> Вызовите `QPixmap::devicePixelRatio()`, чтобы определить, так ли это.
>
> Идентификатор оконной системы (`WId`) можно получить с помощью функции `QWidget::winId()`.
> Обоснование использования идентификатора окна, а не QWidget, состоит в том,
> чтобы разрешить захват окон, которые не являются частью приложения,
> фреймов оконной системы и так далее.
>
> Предупреждение: захват окон, не являющихся частью приложения, не поддерживается в таких системах,
> как `iOS`, где безопасность предотвращает чтение пикселей окон, не принадлежащих приложению.
>
> Функция `grabWindow()` захватывает пиксели с экрана, а не из окна,
> т.е. если есть другое окно частично или полностью поверх того, которое вы захватили,
> вы также получаете пиксели из вышележащего окна.
> Курсор мыши вообще не захватывается.
>
> Обратите внимание на `X11`, что если данное окно не имеет той же глубины,
> что и корневое окно, а другое окно частично или полностью закрывает то,
> которое вы захватили, вы не получите пикселей из вышележащего окна.
> Содержимое закрытых областей в растровом изображении будет неопределенным и неинициализированным.
>
> В Windows Vista и более поздних версиях захват многослойного окна, созданного
> установкой атрибута `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground`, не работает.
> Вместо этого должен работать виджет рабочего стола.
>
> Предупреждение. Как правило, захват области за пределами экрана небезопасен.
> Это зависит от базовой оконной системы.

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, 
                             QGridLayout, QFileDialog, QLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QSizePolicy, QSystemTrayIcon, QStyle, QStackedWidget,
                             QMessageBox, QComboBox, QLineEdit, QStatusBar, 
                             QMainWindow, QToolBar, QErrorMessage, QAction)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPixmap, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QTimer, QDateTime, pyqtSignal, QSize


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)       
        self.parent = parent
        
        self.path = None                               # каталог где следует сохранить файл        
        self.preview_screen = QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(0)  # делает скриншот
        
        self.settings()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.set_layout()

    # вставляет настройки в наше окно
    def settings(self):
        self.setGeometry(972, 395, 370, 270)
        self.setWindowTitle("Скриншот в PyQt5 - `Ctrl+P`")
    
    # создает и настраивает необходимые виджеты    
    def create_widgets(self):
        # создаем ярлык для отображения предварительного скриншота
        self.img_preview = QLabel()
        self.img_preview.setPixmap(self.preview_screen.scaled(self.img_preview.size(),
                                    Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.img_preview.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.img_preview.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.img_preview.setMinimumSize(240, 160)                                    
                                    
        # создаем две кнопки                            
        self.btn_select_path = QPushButton("Выберите путь для сохранения screenshot", self)
        self.btn_new_screenshot  = QPushButton("Сделать screenshot")        
        self.btn_new_screenshot.setShortcut('Ctrl+P')                       
        
        # соединяем кнопки с их соответствующими методами
        self.btn_select_path.clicked.connect(self.select_path)         
        self.btn_new_screenshot.clicked.connect(self.new_screenshot)
     
    # Устанавливаем сетку и добавляем виджеты     
    def set_layout(self):  
        layout = QGridLayout()    
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.img_preview)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_select_path)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn_new_screenshot)
    
    # обновление изображения, присутствующего на ярлыке.
    def new_screenshot(self):
        if self.path == None or self.path == "":
            self.mess_ok1 = "Не указан путь для сохранения screenshot"
            self.mess_ok2 = "Выберите путь для сохранения screenshot."  
            self.downfin()
            return False    
        self.parent.hide()
        
        # после чего берем скриншот (как это делали в инициализаторе класса) и обновляем изображение в ярлыке
        # и, наконец, мы снова показываем наше окно.
        QTimer.singleShot(200, self.take_screenshot)    
        QTimer.singleShot(400, self.screen_save)  
        
    def take_screenshot(self):
        self.preview_screen = QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(0)
        self.img_preview.setPixmap(self.preview_screen.scaled(self.img_preview.size(),
                                        Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.parent.show()                                 
        """
        Вышеупомянутый метод делает снимок экрана и сохраняет его в переменной self.preview_screen, 
        обновляет изображение на этикетке и, наконец, показывает наше приложение обратно. 
        """
    
    def screen_save(self):
        now = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString(Qt.ISODate)
        now = now[0:4]+now[5:7]+now[8:10]+'-'+now[11:13]+now[14:16]+now[17:19]
        img = "%s/%s.png" % (self.path, now)                      
        _   = "PNG(*.png)"                                        
        self.preview_screen.save(img, "png")    

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        scaledSize = self.preview_screen.size()                       
        scaledSize.scale(self.img_preview.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        if not self.img_preview.pixmap() or scaledSize != self.img_preview.pixmap().size():
            self.updateScreenshotLabel()    

    def updateScreenshotLabel(self):
        self.img_preview.setPixmap(self.preview_screen.scaled(        
                self.img_preview.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                Qt.SmoothTransformation))

    def select_path(self):                         # вызов диалогового окна выбора папки для сохранения  
        self.path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Выбрать папку для сохранения screenshot")
        self.btn_select_path.setToolTip('<b>%s</b>' % self.path)

    def downfin(self):                           # для отображения сообщения о ходе выполнения программы
        # Инициализируем QSystemTrayIcon
        self.notifyIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(self)                                     
        self.notifyIcon.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DriveCDIcon))   
        self.notifyIcon.setVisible(True)     # (True) сохраняет, видна ли запись в системном tray/лотке
        self.notifyIcon.showMessage(self.mess_ok1, self.mess_ok2,
                                    QSystemTrayIcon.Information,3000)        


class RestartMainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RestartMainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setGeometry(972, 395, 370, 270)
        self.setWindowTitle('RestartMainWindow: '+path)
        
        if path == "Сделать Скриншот":
            currentWidget = MainWindow(self)                        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)        
        layout.addWidget(currentWidget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w   = RestartMainWindow("Сделать Скриншот")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]