# Как сделать скришот всего экрана (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, экран, screenshots

Как можно сделать скриншот всего экрана чтобы он сохранялся в папку c:\Users\epicb\Desktop/TEST с названием 1.png и в случае если файл с таким именем уже есть чтоб он перезаписывался, я искал в интернете но ничего не нашел, буду благодарен если хотя бы скините ссылку на статью где можно с этим ознакомиться

Comment: отвечает ли это на ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109366/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/1109429#1109429

Comment: нет не отвечает, там вообще про PyQt и про буфер обмена

Comment: Если я в свой проэкт импортирую еще и PyQt то при компиляции в .exe он будет катастрофически много весить

Comment: вы попробовали указанный пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui) есть метод для сохранения скриншота: [.screenshot()](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui#screenshot-functions)

```
import pyautogui

myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'Path to save screenshot\file name.png')
```

Т.е. с вашим адресом будет что-то подобное:

```
myScreenshot.save(r'c:\Users\epicb\Desktop\TEST\1.png')
```

Comment: без pyautogui никак?

Comment: https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot но требует Pillow и Python от 3.6

Comment: если я скомпелирую программу то мой файл весит 40мб, если я еще и pyautohui туда закину то exeшник будет под 60 весить

Comment: @Selasi Если не компилить в один файл можно подцепить embeded версию и в ней потом вручную удалить лишнее (в идеале не сломав все при этом). А вообще python в exe это костыли, если важен размер файла смотрите на компилируемые языки.

Comment: тогда можно попробовать pex