# Создание скриншота, с помощью python, word документа, а точнее таблицы

Tags: python, telegram-bot, ms-word

Я создаю телеграмм бота для работы с расписанием в вузе, мне надо реализовать вывод замен предметов у групп, на сайте вуза их выкладывают в формате MS Word в виде таблицы, я сделал реализацию скачивания с сайта этих замен, но не понимаю как их удобно выводит, но пришла идея делать скрин этой таблицы и выводить ее пользователю, мне надо это автоматизировать, но не знаю как сделать скриншот данной таблицы.
Надеюсь вы знаете как решить эту проблему. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: а отправить пользователю скачанный документ - не вариант? или распарсить, найти замены и отправить только измененившиеся расписания? скрин вордовского документа - как-то не комильфо, имхо

Comment: @Jack_oS суть в том, что вывод предметов будет идти в разнобой, если парсить это все. поэтому я и хочу сделать скрин, чтобы было красиво и удобно, а скидывать файл пользователю тоже не подойдет, так как ему самому придется его скачивать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1236166/420098 ок, пробуйте делать скриншот...