# Можно ли сделать снимок экрана с полноэкранной игры?

Tags: python-3.x, screenshots

Нужно сделать скриншоты с игры, запущенной в полный экран. Пробовал библиотеки `PyAutoGUI`, `Pillow` и `mss`, но проблема в том, что они делают скриншот рабочего стола, но когда игра запущена снимки выходят пустыми.

```
import mss
import pyautogui



def get_screen_height():
    """ Получение высоты экрана """
    return pyautogui.size()[1]


def test_pyautogui():
    area_size = 300
    screen_height = get_screen_height()
    
    pyautogui.screenshot('TESTTESTTEST.png',
        region=(0, screen_height-area_size, area_size, area_size))


def test_mss():
    area_size = 300
    screen_height = get_screen_height()

    with mss.mss() as sct:
        # The screen part to capture
        monitor = {"top": screen_height-area_size, "left": 500, "width": area_size, "height": area_size}
        output = "sct-{top}x{left}_{width}x{height}.png".format(**monitor)

        # Grab the data
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor, mon=1)

        # Save to the picture file
        mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)
        print(output)
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, который делает скриншоты

Comment: добавил пример кода

Comment: а игра у вас в оконном режиме или полный экран ?

Comment: Да. Игра в полноэкранном режиме. Переключив на оконный режим все работает. Но при этом происходит просадка по фпс.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109366/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb/1109429#1109429