# C++ WinAPI Как получить содержимое экрана под окном

Tags: c++, winapi

Как мне получить содержимое экрана под самим окном, не включая его, функция BitBlt() делает по сути скриншот самого окна, а мне нужно только содержимое экрана под окном

Comment: Закрываете окно, делаете скриншот экрана, открываете окно.

Comment: И каким же образом, интересно мне знать, сделать это незаметно для пользователя, ещё и желательно каждый кадр из 60?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109366

Comment: Как сделать скиншот области я в курсе, давайте щас ещё киньте мне OBS и как там видео сохранять, я делаю интерфейс для обычной программы, не игру, мне не надо убивать компьютер пользователя лишней нагрузкой

Comment: Я всё же так понимаю что способ со крином бредовый и самым правильным вариантом будет обратиться к движку сомой винды, он занимается работой с альфа-каналом окна